# How to get currently focused TextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

How can I get the ID of the `TextBox` which is currently focused? If none is focused, it should return a null value.

Note: It should only check text boxes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```cs
TextBox focusedTxt = Controls.OfType<TextBox>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Focused);
```